# Any framework for Adobe Air Application?

Tags: frameworks, adobe, air

I want to used Adobe Air and SQLite (Local Database) in my application.

My Application is little-bit big, so i want to used some framework for this. 
**Is any framework for Adobe Air Application ?**

> Application in not used server site
>   code only client site processing and
>   also used SQLite database on local
>   machine.....

***or any other way which best for Big Air application development***

Comment: You need to specify what tasks should the framework do. By the way, if you use ActionScript for that, all ActionScript frameworks are your candidates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer to this link http://goldsource.de/index.php/as3-resources/frameworks. There are a lot of frameworks, but you need to make a choice depending upon the functionality you require.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this library for your appliation 
https://marpies.com/works/breeze-db/

BreezeDb greatly simplifies the process of setting up, managing and interacting with SQLite database in Adobe AIR. It supports multiple database connections and keeps your app responsive by executing all operations asynchronously.